# MySQL - delete rows rejected on INNODB table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I have two tables - a user table and a userlog table.

```
CREATE TABLE `client_user` (
  `id_client_user` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Nom` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Prenom` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `userid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `lastaccess` timestamp NULL default NULL,
  `user_must_change_pwd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_client_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_log` (
  `id_user_log` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `access` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `zone_updated` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_client_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_user_log`),
  KEY `fk_user_log_client_user1` (`id_client_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_log_client_user1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_client_user`)
      REFERENCES `client_user` (`id_client_user`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I create a user in the client_user table and then his activity is logged within the user_log table.
I now need to delete rows in the user_log table.
This is rejected because of the foreign key constraint - that much I have understood.

After having looked at the documentation, I have not seen how I can change the foreign key to allow me to delete the user_log records.
What I need is a foreign key (1:n), client_user (1) to user_log (n), where user_log records can be deleted without impacting the associated client_user record.

I am sure that this is possible with innodb, but I cannot see how.
Help ?

Comment: You've misunderstood how foreign keys work. You can remove logs without any problem. Just try it!

Comment: You are quite right - stupid me - error in my delete request where I misspelt a field name.  Sorry to have waisted peoples time.

Answer (score 0):

From the [specification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

InnoDB supports the use of ALTER TABLE to drop foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_symbol;
```